# Can't connect to game

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I have two friends who play Age of Empires III and we've been meaning to play a game together. However, we've been running into some weird problems. I cannot connect to any game that involves one of my friends, and he cannot connect to any game I'm in. We've tried ES Online as well as LAN w/ Hamachi.

It doesn't seem to matter who is hosting the game, I just can't seem to connect when that one specific friend is already in the game.

Comment: What exactly happens? You don't see the game listed? You get an error message? What error?